# Await function condition not working properly

Tags: javascript, async-await, apollo-client

Im trying to switch Multiple Apollo client when user Auth/UnAuth situation. 
What i do ?

userCheck() condition not working properly ?

```
async function userCheck() {
  return await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(() => {
      return true;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return false;
    });
}

function createApolloClient(initialState) {
  const client = functionFirst();
  const clientPublic = functionSecond();

  if (userCheck()) {
    return client;
  }
  return clientPublic;
}
```

Comment: `userCheck` returns a Promise which is an Object, which is always _truthy_.

Comment: Update the client or add middlewares to deal with the differences, you shouldn't need to create a new client for each case.